# Selecting the first instance of a specific a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

How do I select only the first instance of a link containing a specific `href`, the solution can be css or javascript, I would prefer css as I need to make styling changes once I have selected the right link but I'm not even sure css can do what I need.

```
<ul class="digital-downloads">
    <li> <a href="order_5129865a7d832&amp;download_file=936">Link</a></li>
    <li> <a href="order_5129870f01410&amp;download_file=936">Link</a></li>
    <li> <a href="order_512a033229f68&amp;download_file=935">Link</a></li>
    <li> <a href="order_512a048548f68&amp;download_file=935">Link</a></li>
    <li> <a href="order_512a0c31734a6&amp;download_file=932">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see by the code above, the first two links aren't identical but they have the same ending. I need a way to select only the *first* instance of a link containing `download_file=936` or `download_file=935` or `download_file=932` etc.

The number of li's will always be different as well as the number of same links so I can't select the third li for example as the link `href` wont always be 935 on the third `li`, it could be 936 or 932 depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a[href*="download_file=935"]:first')
```

To do it in just CSS gets really complicated.

Comment: You'll have to repeat the jQuery selectors for each value, which can be cumbersome (although less so than with just CSS).

Comment: It might be better to use the "attribute ends with" selector:
`$('a[href$="download_file=935"]:first')`. Wouldn't make much of a difference in this case but it's always good to be precise if you know the `download_file` part is always going to be at the end of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) against a jQuery selection, looping over them while comparing against the href from before:

```
var last;
var firsts = $(".digital-downloads li a").filter(function(){
    var link = this.href.match(/download_file=\d+$/)[0];
    if (link == last)
        return false; // we had this before, don't select
    else {
       last = link;
       return true; // we've found a new one!
    }
});
```

In short and taking care of mismatched regex:

```
…
    var m = this.href.match(/download_file=\d+$/);
    return m && m[0] != last && (last=m[0],true);
…
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript:

```
var first = document.querySelector('a[href$="936"]');

first.className = 'first';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BzYA8/).

This approach adds a CSS class-name in order to allow CSS styling, so should combine the benefits of each approach, so long as the browser supports `document.querySelector()`.

Comment: You'll have to repeat this for each value, which can be cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it worked in FF but wouldn't work in IE so i had to go with the solution below and use .addClass() instead of .className

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex:

```
$(function() {
 var count = 0;
 $('a').each(function() {
  var match = $(this).attr('href').match(/(.*download_file=\d+)/);
    if (match !== null && count == 0) {
        alert(match.pop());
        count++;
    }
 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vzJVa/